# Millis () funtion fails to perform for extended period of time

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using millis () function to control the timer of my LED. It is a very basic code that I used from the example libraries. The code worked well for 6 hours (On for 6 h, Off for the following 6 h and continues), however, when I set it up for 12 hours, the light failed to turn off when I checked on it. The designed time should have fit into the 2^32 bits for unsigned long which I have defined beforehand.
Can someone please help on this issue? Thank you!

```
/*
  Blink without Delay

  Turns on and off a light emitting diode (LED) connected to a digital pin,
  without using the delay() function. This means that other code can run at the
  same time without being interrupted by the LED code.

  The circuit:
  - Use the onboard LED.
  - Note: Most Arduinos have an on-board LED you can control. On the UNO, MEGA
    and ZERO it is attached to digital pin 13, on MKR1000 on pin 6. LED_BUILTIN
    is set to the correct LED pin independent of which board is used.
    If you want to know what pin the on-board LED is connected to on your
    Arduino model, check the Technical Specs of your board at:
    https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Products

  created 2005
  by David A. Mellis
  modified 8 Feb 2010
  by Paul Stoffregen
  modified 11 Nov 2013
  by Scott Fitzgerald
  modified 9 Jan 2017
  by Arturo Guadalupi

  This example code is in the public domain.

  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay
*/

// constants won't change. Used here to set a pin number:
const int ledPin =  7;// the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED

// Generally, you should use "unsigned long" for variables that hold time
// The value will quickly become too large for an int to store
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// constants won't change:
unsigned long interval = 12*60*60*1000UL;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.

  // check to see if it's time to blink the LED; that is, if the difference
  // between the current time and last time you blinked the LED is bigger than
  // the interval at which you want to blink the LED.
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

Comment: please look at your post ... does the program listing look the way you intended it to look? ... please format your code ... use the `{}` button

Comment: use `unsigned long interval = 1000UL*12*60*60*; `

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the multiplication operator is “left-associative”. This means
that the expression

```cpp
12*60*60*1000UL
```

is interpreted as

```cpp
((12*60)*60)*1000UL
```

The left factor, namely `(12*60)*60`, is computed using the `int` data
type, but the result overflows that format, resulting in the problem you
see.

The simple solution is to make one of the factors of the *first* product
be an `unsigned long`. For example

```cpp
1000UL*60*60*12
```

Then, `1000UL*60` is computed with the `unsigned long` data type. Since
the result is itself an `unsigned long`, the next multiplication is also
done as `unsigned long`, and likewise for the last one.

If you find this technique somewhat obscure, you can also add the `UL`
suffix to every single factor. This would avoid implicit conversions by
the compiler, making all the types explicit.

Comment: The problem is panned out! Thank you sir! Programming is not my field at all and so I am clearly with no base. Your comment is very helpful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change your variables so that the calculations would be in seconds instead of milliseconds ? IOW add "/1000" after millis() and reduce your constants accordingly.

millis() is overflowing periodically, but it only happens every 49 days or so, and that even shouldn't play a role in the way you use it (the difference will also kind of overflow in the other direction).

Comment: Do not add `/1000` after `millis()`, otherwise you will have a problem when `millis()` rolls over.